# Embarcadero Cbuilder [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::Sysutils::Exception::{1173}...'

Tags: c++, rad-studio

I think that I understand the concept "unresolved external symbol means" - the objects were all compiled and during the linking phase the linker could not find the definition (body) of that particular symbol anywhere. So I guess I either have to use the symbol differently or I have to add to the project some missing system library. I am not sure which is correct and how I can check that (no previous experience with RAD).

I am converting some old code (win95) to  win10, I started a new project under the latest RAD Studio 10.3 and I added all the source files (add to project) manually. I saw an advice here that I should make sure that the compilers are not mixed. I can see that all source files are compiled with bcc32c. In the documentation I can see that Exception basically provides only various constructors http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Exception .

During the linking phase I get the error above - `[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::Sysutils::Exception::{1173}...'`

All the calls were originally Exception("constant") or Exception("constant" + AnsiStringVariable). As most of the problems were caused by old calling schemes I tried to change it to Exception(L"constant") and Exception(L"constant"+UnicodeString), but this is clearly not the problem.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I took the exception-related code from that project and put it into another (empty) project and that links without any issues. Also, I searched for all the usages of the Exception in the original project and I cannot see any overriden version or anything similar. How can I verify that the compiler is set up properly e.g. tries to compile c instead of c++ or different standard? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So clearly this code:

```
 if(x!=S0getb()) Exception("Bad final checksum!");
```

generates the error in question. The problem is the missing `throw`. Probably it somehow compiled in the previous versions and nobody noticed. I guess there is a difference between en error code for a missing function symbol and a missing class symbol. But I did not recognized that this is a function call while it should be a new class instance.

The correct code:

```
 if(x!=S0getb()) throw Exception("Bad final checksum!");
```

fixes the issue.